# How to Pass Struct Data Member into Function

Tags: c++, function

I want to be able to pass a struct member into a function:

```
struct threeBuckets {
  int bucketA;
  int bucketB;
  int bucketC;
};

threeBuckets allCombinations[512000] = {{0,0,0}};  
int totalCombinations = 1;
int counter = 0;


//note that pourer, receiver, and other are one of the struct members (bucketA, bucketB, and bucketC)

void pour(pourer, receiver, int receiverCap, other) {
  int finalTriple[3];
  allCombinations[totalCombinations].bucketA = allCombinations[counter].bucketA;
  allCombinations[totalCombinations].bucketB = allCombinations[counter].bucketB;
  allCombinations[totalCombinations].bucketC = allCombinations[counter].bucketC;
  allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver = allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver + allCombinations[counter].pourer;
  allCombinations[totalCombinations].pourer = 0;
  if (allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver > receiverCap) {
    allCombinations[totalCombinations].pourer = allCombinations[totalCombinations].pourer + allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver - receiverCap;
    allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver = receiverCap;
  }
  finalTriple[0] = allCombinations[totalCombinations].bucketA;
  finalTriple[1] = allCombinations[totalCombinations].bucketB;
  finalTriple[2] = allCombinations[totalCombinations].bucketC;
//some more irrelevant code
}
```

As I've hopefully made clear, the parameters pourer, receiver, and other are bucketA, bucketB, and bucketC (in no particular order, the order does change depending on when I call the function.) There are several places where I want to modify the instance

```
allCombinations[totalCombinations].pourer
```

for example. How do I use the struct member as a parameter, and what type do I use to specify it?

Note: I'm mostly a beginner and am new to StackOverflow, so if anything else I'm doing is wrong, please feel free to tell me.

Note 2: If any of you do or have done USACO, you might recognize this problem as the milk3 training gateway problem. This might aid you if you don't know what I'm doing here.

Comment: I don't understand, why not pass the entire structure, by reference, to your function?  When passing by reference, there is less overhead than passing two or more members separately.

Comment: Your `pour` function is missing type identifiers in the function declaration and definition.

Comment: Your `threeBuckets` structure is missing the members `receivier` and `pourer`.

Comment: BTW, you can assign instances of structures without having to assign individual members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use pointer to member variable for the argument types in `pour`.

```
void pour(double threeBuckets::(*pourer) ,
          double threeBuckets::(*receiver),
          int receiverCap,
          double threeBuckets::(*other)) { 
   ...
}
```

In the function, change the use of

```
allCombinations[totalCombinations].pourer
allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver
allCombinations[totalCombinations].other
```

by

```
allCombinations[totalCombinations].*pourer
allCombinations[totalCombinations].*receiver
allCombinations[totalCombinations].*other
```

respectively.

At the point of calling the function, use:

```
pour(&threeBuckets::bucketA,
     &threeBuckets::bucketB,
     0, // Any appropriate value
     &threeBuckets::bucketC);
```

---

Another option that is worth considering is:

1. Change `threeBuckets` to use an array.
2. Change the arguments to `pour` to be indices to the array.

```
struct threeBuckets {
  int buckets[3];
};

void pour(int pourerIndex ,
          int receiverIndex,
          int receiverCap,
          int otherIndex)) { 
   ...
}
```

Then, instead of using

```
allCombinations[totalCombinations].pourer
allCombinations[totalCombinations].receiver
allCombinations[totalCombinations].other
```

use

```
allCombinations[totalCombinations].buckets[pourerIndex]
allCombinations[totalCombinations].buckets[receiverIndex]
allCombinations[totalCombinations].buckets[otherIndex]
```

Of course, change the call to use indices.

```
pour(0,
     1
     0, // Any appropriate value
     2);
```